# How to render pdf from angular io (5) sites with phantomjs

Tags: node.js, angular, phantomjs

I just put some image and try to render pdf:

```
phantom.create().then(async function(ph) {
    let page = await ph.createPage();
    let status = await page.open("http://localhost:4000")
    await page.render('file.pdf');
    ph.exit();
});
```

But i get blank pdf file.

I also try

```
page.onLoadFinished
```

But it is never income to it.

I also try:

```
 await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 10000));
```

But nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running phantom alone, and figure out that i need to uncomment this lines in polyfills:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```